# Pandas centred rolling window rank returns wrong value

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I'm trying to calculate the rank of a column value within a rolling window in Pandas like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( [[1, 10],
                    [2, 20],
                    [3, 50],
                    [4, 30],
                    [5, 40]], 
                   columns=['order_col', 'rank_col'])
df['rank'] = df.rolling(3, center=True, min_periods=1, on='order_col')['rank_col'].rank()
```

The result of rank() though gives the rank of the **last** row in the window not the one in the centre, as expected:

[image: image of DataFrame]

Any ideas how I can get the rank of the correct row? I.e. I expect the ranks to be 1, 2, 3, 1, 2

**EDIT**: I chose a small example to illustrate the problem but in actuality my dataframe has thousands of rows and the rolling window is of size 100+ rows.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a workaround, you'd use rank in apply and explicitly take the center value.

The code inspects the index of the series to recognize that it's the first window and not the last.

```
def series_rank_center(series):
    if 1 in series.index and len(series) < 3:
        return series.rank().iat[0]  # center value for first window
    else:
        return series.rank().iat[1]  # center value

df.rolling(3, center=True, min_periods=1, on='order_col').apply(series_rank_center)
```

```
   order_col  rank_col
0          1       1.0
1          2       2.0
2          3       3.0
3          4       1.0
4          5       2.0
```

Comment: Ah, that's ace! But I only set the rolling window size to 3 for clarity in the example.  Actually the window size will be something like 100 and the size of the dataframe is in the thousands of rows.  But I think re-indexing, accessing the index and considering the length etc will work.  I did not know how to access the index in that way.  I'll edit the question.  Thx!

Comment: `order_col` shows up as index here just as an effect of rolling's `on` parameter.

Comment: @dee_jay_jay IMO, consider raising a general feature request with pandas about taking the center value.